# Amazon Cognito Sync (Data not Syncing across multiple devices)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use Amazon Cognito Sync (In Javascript) to sync my data across multiple devices, Syncing between 
the amazon console (Server) and my device is working fine, **but when i use the same credentials (ie database name and )**, to retrieve data, in an
another device it shows empty list (Another Identity entry is created, with no data).  **Enable access to unauthenticated identities is checked**

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on the forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=780302&#780302